# Storing line from standard input never changes

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm working on this problem([Uva227](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=163)).I've almost received correct results when I test the cases, but I've met a problem. I used function gets() to get a line from standard input, and store it in a[0]. but after the first input matrix, a[0] never changes anymore. What's wrong with it?

P.S. In Puzzle #2(i.e., the second input matrix), a[0] didn't changed, so I got a wrong answer. But if I put it first, it returned a correct output. So I think the algorithm is correct, but something went wrong when reading the first line.

English is not my native language; please excuse my syntax errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char a[5][5];



int main(){
    int _case = 1;
    char c;
    while(gets(a[0])){//Please focus on this line;it seems that a[0] never changed since first reading.
        if(a[0][0] == 'Z')  break;
        int blank_i, blank_j;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if(i)   gets(a[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                if(a[i][j] == ' '){
                     blank_i = i;
                     blank_j = j;
                }
            }
        }
        bool flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        while((c = getchar()) != '0'){
            switch(c){
                case 'A':
                    a[blank_i][blank_j] = a[blank_i - 1][blank_j];
                    a[--blank_i][blank_j] = ' ';    break;
                case 'B':
                    a[blank_i][blank_j] = a[blank_i + 1][blank_j];
                    a[++blank_i][blank_j] = ' ';    break;
                case 'L':
                    a[blank_i][blank_j] = a[blank_i][blank_j - 1];
                    a[blank_i][--blank_j] = ' ';    break;
                case 'R':
                    a[blank_i][blank_j] = a[blank_i][blank_j + 1];
                    a[blank_i][++blank_j] = ' ';    break;
                default:    break;
             }
        }
        //add a getchar() here will fix the problem.
        printf("Puzzle #%d:\n", _case);
        if(blank_i < 0 || blank_i > 4 || blank_j < 0 || blank_j >  4)
             printf("This puzzle has no final configuration.\n");
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                    printf("%c ", a[i][j]);
                }
            printf("\n");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        _case++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use gets. It's a dangerous function. Use fgets instead.

Comment: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) Use `if (fgets (a[i], 5, stdin)) a[i][strcspn(a[i], "\n")] = 0; else { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. It's not the case that "after the first input matrix, a[0] never changes anymore." The actual problem is that after you read the `'0'` that ends the list of moves, there's a newline before the next puzzle begins. Your code doesn't take this into account, and so treats the newline as the first character of the first line of the next puzzle. Fix it by swallowing this newline before getting back to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Aside: Some commenters pointed out that you shouldn't use `gets`. They're 100% right, but it's not related to this problem, and switching away from it won't fix this.

Comment: *"switching away from it won't fix this."* - true, but it *will* bring compliance to the C code itself, since `gets` was completely removed from the standard library starting in C11. I'm not surprised, but rather disappointed that UVA isn't using C11 compliance, in which case the code wouldn't just deliver a wrong answer; it wouldn't even *compile*. Regardless, have an uptick.

Comment: I added a getchar() before output the matrix and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In additions to Joeseph's answer, you invite *Undefined Behavior* by failing to validate that your `i, j, blank_i, blank_j` indexes remain in bounds. (and *Never, ever use `gets()` it has been removed from the current C standard). See: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Instead, use `fgets` and trim the trailing `'\n'` from the resulting string by overwriting with the *nul-characer*, e.g.

```
#define ROWS 5      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS ROWS

char a[ROWS][COLS];
...
        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            if (i)                                  /* skips a[0] */
                if (fgets (a[i], COLS, stdin))
                    a[i][strcspn(a[i], "\n")] = 0;  /* overwrite '\n' */
                else {  /* handle failed input */
                    fputs ("error: EOF encountered.\n", stderr);
                    return 1;
                }
           ...
```

Next, in the following `for` loop you assign `blank_i = i;` and `blank_j = j;`, e.g.

```
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
                if(a[i][j] == ' ') {
                     blank_i = i;
                     blank_j = j;
                }
            }
```

Subsequently, you then increment `a[blank_i++][blank_j];` and used `blank_j--` and `blank_j++` (you must also ensure `blank_i--` never results in a negative value). To avoid *Undefined Behavior*, you must validate your indexes remain in range. For example, taking your `case 'B':`, you can do something similar to:

```
                case 'B':
                    {   /* create new block to allow variable declaration
                         * blank_i + 1 can exceed 4 invokding Undefined
                         * Behavior. You must validate/handle value.
                         */
                        int row = blank_i + 1 % ROWS;
                        a[blank_i][blank_j] = a[row][blank_j];
                        /* same with ++blank_i */
                        blank_i = (blank_i + 1) % ROWS;
                        a[blank_i][blank_j] = ' ';
                        break;  /* lines don't cost $, done hide break at end */
                    }
```

Since you are looping `while ((c = getchar()) != '0')` both values `blank_i` and `blank_j` can exceed your array bounds or result in a negative index invoking *Undefined Behavior* -- long before your ever check:

```
        printf("Puzzle #%d:\n", _case);
        if(blank_i < 0 || blank_i > 4 || blank_j < 0 || blank_j >  4)
             printf("This puzzle has no final configuration.\n");
```

Go through and fix your indexing (handling it any way you need) to validate your indexes remain within the bounds of your array.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. It's very kind of you to give me these advices.